# Use pointer or reference to check whether object is contained

Tags: c++

I have a Simulation class which owns a vector of Sensors. Would you prefer `containsSensor1(const Sensor* iSen)` or `containsSensor2(const Sensor& iSen)` to check if a sensor is contained? Generally I would always prefer the const reference function but in this case I'm not sure which one is more convenient.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Sensor
{
};

class Simulation
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Sensor>> sensors;

public:
    void addSensor(std::unique_ptr<Sensor> iSen)
    {
        sensors.push_back(std::move(iSen));
    }
    bool containsSensor1(const Sensor* iSen) const
    {
        bool rv = false;
        for (auto itr = sensors.begin(); itr != sensors.end(); ++itr)
        {
            if (itr->get() == iSen)
            {
                rv = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }
    bool containsSensor2(const Sensor& iSen) const
    {
        bool rv = false;
        for (auto itr = sensors.begin(); itr != sensors.end(); ++itr)
        {
            if (itr->get() == &iSen)
            {
                rv = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }    
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Sensor> sen1 = std::make_unique<Sensor>();
    const Sensor* sen1Ptr = sen1.get();
    Simulation sim;
    sim.addSensor(std::move(sen1));

    bool contains1 = sim.containsSensor1(sen1Ptr);
    bool contains2 = sim.containsSensor2(*sen1Ptr);

    std::cout << contains1 << "\n" << contains2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**
I don't want to check for object equality. I just want to know if a sensor added before is still contained in the simulation object (in reality there is also a removeSensor function)

Comment: This is an opinion based question and that is generally frowned upon on here. However, I think exposing the pointer after wrapping it in a `unique_ptr` is poor design as well. Seems like  case where you would want to use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ref` instead.

Comment: While the answer to your question could potentially be based on opinion, the one thing that you have to do first is figure out a ownership policy. Who owns the sensors? Who is responsible for deleting them?
 After that, it will be easier to figure out which one of those will be a better option.

Comment: Since objects are identified by their address, I find a reference interface confusing.

Comment: @ R Sahu: The owner of the sensor after calling addSensor is the Simulation object. The function signature of addSensor should answer the question.

Comment: You have a bigger issue than deciding between a reference or a pointer in `constainsSensor`. You are handing out raw pointers to your sensors, which defeats the purpose of using smart pointers `std::unique_ptr`. I would say either create an interface so that the user doesn't have to interact with the pointers directly, or use `shared_ptr`. In the ladder case, you should probably use a reference in `containsSensor`, otherwise you have to dereference smart pointers twice.

Comment: I don't want to use `shared_ptr` because the Sensors should be owned by the 'Simulation'.

Comment: Use `weak_ptr` in `get()` then. It allows you to hand out pointers without giving ownership - only temporary. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr

Comment: `weak_ptr`can only be used in combination with `shared_ptr`

Comment: Yes, use `shared_ptr` internally and hand out `weak_ptr`. It's just a suggestion though, but raw pointers are definitely a no-no, you can very easily get dangling pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely subjective. I like the reference for it but, assuming that you're locked into using the object's address as unique ID, honestly you can do whichever you like.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is slightly clearer from the reference method that you are trying to look up the matching Sensor object within the Simulation rather than attempting to possibly match the pointers themselves.

It may be less complex to use a `vector<Sensor>` and then use a Sensor move constructor to move the Sensor into the vector. Then you would definitely use the reference approach. Combine that with a `std::find` to check that the object exists within the vector.